# Oracle Time Zones Conversion (using from_tz)

Tags: oracle, date, time, timezone

I'm trying to convert a time (date + time) from one time zone to another. In the query below, I'm trying to convert a time from EST ("America/New_York") to PST ("America/Los_Angeles"). The query is partially working; the results:

```
DATABASE_DATE = 2012-02-13 1:00:00 PM  
LOCALTIME (what I get): 2012-02-12 10:00:00 AM.
```

So the time is good but the date is wrong.  It should be 2012-02-13 instead of 2012-02-12.

Am I doing something wrong? Here's my query:

```
select to_date( to_char( ( from_tz( to_timestamp( DATABASE_DATE
                                                 , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')
                                   ,'America/New_York')
                          at time zone 'America/Los_Angeles')
                       ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')
               ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') as localtime
 from table
```

Thanks

Comment: did you try to add "PM" to the format string ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried with "PM" and I get the same results.

Comment: just to be sure - DATABASE_DATE is a string not a date, right ? because, otherwise it will convert it according to nls_timestamp_format which might be 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'

Comment: DATABASE_DATE is the name of the field containing the date I want to convert.

Comment: Ok. Just changed the nls_date_format: alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS PM' and it's working.

Comment: Don't use to_timestamp on dates, use to_char first (instead of changing nls_date_format)

Comment: Could guide me a bit on that one.  How can I use to_char instead of to_timestamp in my query ?

Comment: added it as an answer (actually you did something like it in your query)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

to_timestamp() gets a string (VARCHAR2, CHAR ...) if you try to give it a date, then oracle will convert it to a string according to NLS_DATE_FORMAT which might vary in different environments and return unexpected results (as in this case).
What you should do is use to_char first, so your query can look like this:

```
select to_date(to_char((from_tz(to_timestamp(to_char(DATABASE_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS PM'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS PM') ,'America/New_York')
at time zone 'America/Los_Angeles'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS PM'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS PM') as localtime
from table
```

**UPDATE:** if I understand you right then you want something like this:

```
select to_char((from_tz(to_timestamp(to_char(DATABASE_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS PM'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS PM') ,'America/New_York')
    at time zone 'America/Los_Angeles'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS PM TZD') as localtime
    from table
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and the help with the query. Really appreciated.

Comment: A.B. Cade: I have another question if you don't mind.  In my query, I convert the time from 'America/New_York' to 'America/Los_Angeles'.  Is it also possible to get the time zone abbreviation ('PST') on top of converting the time.  So if the time in New York is 2012-02-14 01:00 PM I could get 2012-02-14 10:00 AM **PST** for Los Angeles.

Comment: If I understand you right, then you don't want to get a Date but a VARCHAR2 which shows the date formatted and includes at the end the abbreviation. So, you need to remove the upper "to_date" (since you don't want a date) and add to the to_char's format "TZD"

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(NEW_TIME(systimestamp,'EST','PST'), 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS') AS converted_timestamp_column FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: That function `NEW_TIME` works only for a *very* limited number of timezones, see https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/NEW_TIME.html#GUID-1D1CC7DE-CA2A-4BEC-B404-89FD19EE36AC.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this as well .There is a function for this purpose in oracle

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2036.htm

```
select NEW_TIME (TO_DATE ('2011/11/11 01:45', 'yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI'), 'AST', 'MST') from dual;
```