# Unix timestamp to oracle timestamp

Tags: oracle, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I'm using Oracle Express 11g.

I have a table named rm_pedidos that has a column named 'fechacreacion', declared as timestamp(0) [so milliseconds part are not stored]

I have a record in that table, whose fechacreacion is (in unix time, it's the one I inserted): 1418533255000 (that's Sat Dec 13 2014 23:00:55.000000000 GMT-0600 (CST))

This query works (it returns that row):

```
select * from rm_pedidos where fechacreacion = (timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00 +00:00' + numtodsinterval(1418533255000/1000,'second'))
```

So I thought, let's create a function:

```
create or replace function to_ts(p_millis in number) return timestamp is
begin
  return timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00 +00:00' + numtodsinterval(p_millis/1000,'second');
end;
```

I tested it:

```
select to_ts(1418533255000) from dual
```

It returns (display in SQLDeveloper): 14/12/14 05:00:55.000000000 (fine, it's in GMT+0, which is the same as Sat Dec 13 2014 23:00:55 GMT-0600)

But when I used it in the query:

```
select * from rm_pedidos where fechacreacion = to_ts(1418533255000)
```

No row was returned.

Can you explain what's going on? Is it something wrong in my function?

Thanks in advance,
Raka

---

ADDITIONAL INFO

I just made this test (on SqlDeveloper):

```
select to_ts(1418533255000) from dual;
```

it shows: 14/12/14 05:00:55.000000000

But this statement:

```
select timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00 +00:00' + numtodsinterval(1418533255000/1000,'second') from dual;
```

shows: 14/12/14 05:00:55.000000000 +00:00

The difference: this timestamp returned by to_ts(...) does not carry the tz information (so I guess it assumes local time zone... 14/12/14 05:00:55.000000000 -06:00.

How to implement to_ts(...) such that it returns a timestamp with tz information (in this case I want +00:00 as tz)?

Thanks!

---

MORE ADDITIONAL INFO

I've even tried this acrobat just to get the value returned by to_ts carry the tz info.... Still, no luck:

```
create or replace function to_ts(p_millis in number)
return timestamp is
begin
  return TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(
    concat(
      to_char(timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00 +00:00' + numtodsinterval(p_millis/1000,'second'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 
      ' +00:00'
    ),
    'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS +TZH:TZM'
  );
end;
```

"select to_ts(1418533255000) from dual;" still shows 14/12/14 05:00:55.000000000 ... and "select * from rm_pedidos where fechacreacion = to_ts(1418533255000)" still returns no record.

---

ADDITIONAL NOTE (CURRENT WORKAROUND)

I just found out... this query works:

```
select * from rm_pedidos where fechacreacion = from_tz(to_ts(1418533255000), '0:00');
```

So.., I have to invoke from_tz on the return value from to_ts (...weird enough though, doing this inside the function to_ts doesn't work).

Really, oracle?

---

OK: Finally... (it was my bad). This one works (I should've declared the return type as 'timestamp with time zone':

```
create or replace function to_ts(p_millis in number) return TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE is
begin
  return timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00 +00:00' + numtodsinterval(p_millis/1000,'second');
end;
```

This way, this simple query works:

```
select * from rm_pedidos where fechacreacion = to_ts(1418533255000);
```

And so do these queries:

```
select * from rm_pedidos where fechacreacion < to_ts(1418533255001);
select * from rm_pedidos where fechacreacion > to_ts(1418533254999);
```

Comment: I'm thinking of macro now.... Is there such thing in plsql?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, just keeping it around, just in case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264350/oracle-time-zones-conversion-using-from-tz